# HTML5 video not playing in Firefox 3.6

Tags: html, firefox, browser, html5-video

I have the following code to play HTML5 video on website:

```
<video autoplay loop poster="">

    <source src="http://www.domain.com/uploads/videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4;">
    <source src="http://www.domain.com/uploads/videos/video.webm" type="video/webm"/>
    <source src="http://www.domain.com/uploads/videos/video.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>

    <p> Your browser does not support HTML5 video. Please upgrade to a modern browser to view the video.</p>

</video>
```

I tried this on Firefox 3.6 and it shows a blank page instead of playing the video. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox 3.6 [does support HTML 5 video](http://caniuse.com/video), so the behaviour you are experiencing is correct.

Use [JavaScript to detect when no sources have loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Detecting_when_no_sources_have_loaded) and provide alternatives with DOM manipulation.

Comment: I thought .ogg was supported by Firefox, why won't the video load then?

Answer (score 1):

Your server is probably serving it as application/octet-stream.

Check your content types are correct:

```
.ogg application/ogg
.ogv video/ogg
.mp4 video/mp4
```

I don't know your server setup but if you are using apache add this to your .htaccess:

```
AddType application/ogg .ogg
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/webm .webm
```

Comment: In which directory should the .htaccess file be placed? I tried placing it in the main folder and in the video uploads folder but didn't work. Thanks